# how to increment by one using react

Tags: reactjs

first time ever asking a question, sorry if I am not posting correctly,
I'm a little confused as to why this will not increment

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heading: "Deconstruct Topic:",
      topics: [
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "all topics",
          node: " all upperlevel"
        }
      ]
    };
    }
    handleSubmitTopicDecon = e => {
     e.preventDefault();

    const topics = this.state.topics.slice();
    console.log(topics, "topics");
    topics.push({
      id: this.state.id + 1,
      name: this.state.newName,
      node: this.state.newNode
    });
    console.log(this.state.id, "id");
    this.setState({ topics });
  };
```

I keep getting id is not a number???
any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Because You haven't defined an `id` item in `this.state` what you have is an `id` element inside `this.state.topics[0]`(ie, `this.state.topics[0].id`)

Comment: You can not change the const value. Use var, or let.    also can not see the this.state.id, this.state.newName, this.state.newNode. They are not declared

Comment: thank you for the prompt responses, i'm still not completely understanding, as far as the slice method is concerned i do not believe having const affects anything, i have tried let and var, does not change anything, because i am pushing a new array with index of 1,2,3.. so forth, if index topics[0] has id of 0, i wish for topics[1] to have id of 1 and topics[2] to have index of 2 everytime i invoke the handle submit, that would be my goal

Comment: *sorry pushing a new object not array, ... i am pushing a new object into the array with the slice method

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `this.state` like this:

```
this.state = {
    heading: "Deconstruct Topic:",
    topics: [{
        id: 0,
        name: "all topics",
        node: " all upperlevel"
    }
]
```

As you can see, there is not `id` member directly under `this.state`, only under `this.state.topics[0]`.

When you access `this.state.id` you get `undefined` and then you try to increment it and get the error.

Go over what you wanted to accomplish here and rewrite your code accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your response, i have tried to update id: this.state.topics.id + 1, in my handleSubmitTopicDecon method... this does not help, what i am currently doing with my component , that i am not fully showing, is that in my render section, i have the handlesubmitTopicDecon method connected to a button, so that a new  object gets pushed each time the button is clicked and then i have a map function to render each object, in a separate component. my goal would be to have topics[0] to have an id of 0, topics[1] to have an id of 1 topics[2] to have an id of two and so forth.

Comment: ``` handleSubmitTopicDecon = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let topics = this.state.topics.slice();
    console.log(topics, "topics");
    topics.push({
      id: this.state.topics.id + 1,
      name: this.state.newName,
      node: this.state.newNode
    });
    console.log(this.state.id, "id");
    this.setState({ topics });
  };```

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This page is for deconstructing a topic of choice</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.heading} </h2>
        <Topics topics={this.state.topics} />
.... <button onClick={this.handleSubmitTopicDecon}>Add Topic</button>

Comment: const Topics = props => {
  console.log(props.topics, "props");
  return (
    <div>
      {props.topics.map(topics => {
        return <Topic key={topics.id} topics={topics} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Topics;

Comment: when i go into my browser web tools console: i get the following:

Comment: 0:{id: 0, name: "all topics", node: " all upperlevel"}
1:{id: NaN, name: "asdfasdf", node: "asdfasdf"}

Answer (score -1):

You have declared topics variable as const.You cannot change const variables after they are declared. Change it to this code and try it once again:

var topics = this.state.topics.slice();

Comment: that's not true for objects and arrays